# Tracert output- trying to understand what to expect

Tags: networking, router, traceroute

For example, if I typed

> tracert www.facebook.com

I would expect to see the path taken by the packets whilst it is travelling to reach the website, along with the routers it has passed with the hop time also recorded. I also believe that the field of the IP header contains the TTL when becomes 0, is dropped by the receiving sender and notified to the original sender. (Please let me know if I am wrong)

However, my questions are: If I had mistyped my website name what output would I expect, and also would this command give me the exact same (for www.facebook.com) output for any time of the day? I would have thought due to peak times having busier routers with more delays it would vary, however, I was hoping somebody could explain better what is going on.

Comment: Routes to an end-point are complicated. Sometimes you will always take the same route, sometimes you won't. It really depends on the end-point and what is in between. First you should keep in mind that there may be different owners for many of the hops between both end-points (not just ISPs) - and each hop owner may set up the routes to be static, or by one of many dynamic routing protocols. This means that your routes to facebook will be different based on where you initiate the tracert and may change in different ways. For some it may be static, for others it won't be.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be always directed by the 'correct' site -> the site with the EXACT  name you typed. Which may not be "the isite you're looking for" but, as typo is your, the answer given by the DNS is correct (as it will check exactly what you asked). This is used in some spoofing attaks where attackers register 'similar' names (I bet you cannot find the difference between the difference between "x" and unicode character x0445).
About 'time of day' It depends, maybe the site may have all front ends responding to same IP and managing the load balancing 'inside' (so the IP will always be the same) or it can have a pool of IPs 'rotating' to allow dispatching to multiple hosts (a classical example of varying IP). these are just examples.